# Do i need index for composite primary key where each column is foreign key

Tags: postgresql

When i create table user:

```
pk
id | int
```

And table friend:

```
pk, fk  | pk, fk
user_id | friend_id
```

As i understand composite pk creates unique index user_id+friend_id internally and this index is used for user_id foreign key. But do i need to create index for friend_id because index on composite pk friend table will not work for friend_id (it's second in composite pk)?

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE public."user"
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass),
)



CREATE TABLE public.user_friend
(
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    friend_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_friend_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id, friend_id),
    CONSTRAINT user_friend_friend_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (friend_id)
        REFERENCES public."user" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT user_friend_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public."user" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)


CREATE INDEX fki_user_friend_friend_id_fkey
    ON public.user_friend USING btree
    (friend_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: Yes, for a query that looks up users who have x as their friend, such an index would be useful. That there are foreign key references is pretty much irrelevant for this, though.

Comment: @Bergi i will not use such a query. But why is irrelevant if every time i insert in friend table, postgres need to be sure thats foreign keys is okay and if for user_id check it can use primary key index, for friend_id it will not work?

Comment: The foreign keys are pointing to the `user.id` column if I understood correctly? (It would help if you could post the table definitions as SQL). That will use the primary key `id` index on the `user` table for checking whether the inserted `user_id` and `friend_id` values are ok. The indices on the `friend` table are not used for checking foreign key integrity. (They do become relevant when you delete or update the `id` of a `user` however).

Comment: @Bergi posted sql. Yes there is cascade foreach column. Please answer so i could accept it. I think i understand now. Inserts use user index, but if i change user id, than i need index in friend table.

Comment: @Bergi rarelly, hm, you right, i don't really need index on friends then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As i understand composite pk creates unique index user_id+friend_id intenally

Yes.

> and this index is used for user_id foreign key.

Not exactly, no.

There are two cases here:

- an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` on the `user_friend` table. It will have to check the table's primary key of course (and will use the `user_friend_pkey` index for that). For the foreign key constraints, this will only have to check whether the `user_id` and `friend_id` values exist in the `user` table, and will use the index created by `user`'s primary key for those.
- an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` on the `user` table. It will have to check whether the old value was referenced in the `user_friend` table, and act according to the `CASCADE` or `RESTRICT` strategy. To find this row in `user_friend`, it will use the indices on `user_id` and on `friend_id` if they exist.

> But do i need to create index for friend_id because index on composite pk friend table will not work for friend_id

Yes, looking up by `friend_id` is slow without the extra index. You only need this if you want to find users that have x as their friend, or when updates/deletes on `user` must not be slow.

Comment: Just to make sure, if i 'select * from user_friend where user_id=smth' or for an UPDATE id or DELETE user on the user table i dont need to create user_id index in user_friend table because it will use pk index on user_friend table.

Comment: `select * from friend_user where user_id=smth` will work fine with the `user_friend_pkey` index, yes. `update "user" set id=smth`/`delete "user" where id=smth` will also use that index for updating `user_friend` rows whose `user_id` references the updated/deleted `user.id`. However, for updating the `user_friend` rows whose `friend_id` references the updated/deleted `user.id`, this will not work - that's what you need an extra index on `friend_id` for.